# How can I stop processing of non-existent domains?

Tags: .htaccess, server, dns, subdomain

Our website is allowing any prefix/subdomain before the domain.

So if our site is www.domain.com, then the server is allowing;
www.anything.domain.com, where 'anything' can be literally anything, and it displays whatever is on the page that actually exists.

So, www.anything.domain.com/something.php displays the content that should only be accessible via www.domain.com/something.php.

Is there any way using .htaccess to stop this from happening, or redirect it to the version that does actually exist?

Or does this need to be done on the server?

Does anyone know why this is being allowed?

Comment: Do you have access to server (apache) `.conf` files?

Comment: Thanks for the response.
If I don't currently, then I can get in touch with the guys who take care of our hosting.
What would need to be added/adjusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, this should be configured in server configuration files (also, you can configure DNS to simply not resolve unwanted hostnames, but that is for another question probably).

If you don't have access to server configuration, you can do it in `.htaccess`:

```
# to block access if any domain except example.com or www.example.com was used
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !=www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !=example.com
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

or

```
# if any domain except example.com or www.example.com was used, 
# redirect the request to www.example
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !=www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !=example.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```